# Div of roll over menu doesnot resize it's size with child element

Tags: html, css

[image: roll over menu]

The list menu is re-size but the container div seem not re-size its size. 
This is the image of my menu. I tried lots of solution but it didn't work.
Here are some style of the div container :

```
#container{
margin-left: 4px;
margin-right: 8px;
padding-top: 12px;
position: relative;
top: -11px;
}
```

Here is my div:

```
<div id="categoryTab">
<%  
   string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
   if (url.ToLower().Contains("Test/TestW".ToLower()){
      Response.Write("<ul id='aa'>");         
   }
   else
   {
      Response.Write("<ul id='bb-v'>");         
   }
%>
<% foreach (var a in Model.Department)
{ %>
<li>   
This is my text.
<% if (a.Categories.Count() > 0){ %>
   <ul style="z-index:0;">
    <% foreach (var b in ci.Distinct()){ %>
      <div style="z-index:0;">
        <li>
          Sub menu   
        </li>                 
       </div>                 
    </ul>

        <%}
        }%>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me please. 
Thanks.

Comment: Anyone know about it? Please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you would need to set a position absolute on the submenu so that it would be removed from the flow of the dive but be positioned inside the container div.  I think the more appropriate way would be float but without seeing more code it would be hard to say